# Can't get Mobiscroll ListView to work

Tags: jquery, mobiscroll

I'm getting the error bellow on the browser Javascript console when the page loads thus the control doesn't get created:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'listview'

**HTML**

```
<ul id="list">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <!-- List can contain optional list dividers to group items -->
  <li data-role="list-divider">List divider</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
</ul>
```

**JS:**

```
$('#list').mobiscroll().listview({
  theme: 'ios',
  sortable: true
});
```

I'm using the latest version from GitHub.

Does this list component require a subscription?

[Fiddler Sample](http://jsfiddle.net/2eTEp/3/)

Comment: jQM uses `.listview()`, so it looks like a conflict between both.

Comment: I'm not using jQM, only jQuery is being loaded on the JSFiddle.

Comment: So you aren't using jQM?

Comment: That's right, I'm only using Mobiscroll's JavaScript files (http://docs.mobiscroll.com/).

Comment: Ok, so I added a references to jQM but still got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I have confirmed that the Listview is a commercial component and will not work out of the GitHub repository.